# Algorithm to find all values repeating more than floor(n/k) times in O(n log k) time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, theory

Given a parameter `k` and an array (not sorted) of length `n` return all values which repeat more than floor(n/k) times in O(n log k) time.

I've managed this in O(nk) time can't figure out how to do it in the required performance.

Comment: Can you give a sample input/output?

Comment: for example: A=1,1,1,2,3 then n=5 so for k=2 we need to find all values which repeat more than floor(5/2)=2 times so the output would be just the value 1.

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: no. I'll add that to the question text

Comment: @user3386109 would be O(n) if it was ^^

Comment: Since you don't mention the preferred programming language for the answer, I can provide you the algorithm in words. First, you can pick up some sorting algorithm for the given array. The best sorting is O(n log k) time. Once you have the array sorted, you can pass only once and get the elements values which repeat more than floor(n/k) times. Hope this helps.

Comment: @juvian True. My point was more that the example should be representative of the actual problem. Also, the example should be in the question itself.

Comment: @KrassiEm how is sorting not n log n?

Comment: Hi juvian, my understanding is that the difference between values O(n log k) and    O(n log n) is not that significant compared to quadratic time complexity. In fact, it might be a catch the  O(n log k). If the condition were  O(n log n), the first thing that comes to mind is to sort it and then just sequentially count. There might be even faster ways, maybe pass once and build a hash table for each element of the array and then count if it is there already...

Comment: You can do this in O(n) if the output doesn't have to be sorted.

Comment: @KrassiEm sorting is O(n log n) not O(n log k) right? so that doesn't really work for K smaller than n I think.

Comment: @rici The output does not need to be sorted. How can it be done in O(n)?

Comment: Jason, you have to use a hash table or a binary tree - whichever you choose, to make the fastest possible program. Search for a value in the hash is O(1), and if an element is there, just increment the counter for the respective element.

Comment: @Jason can you explain your O(nk) method?

Comment: @juvian True. But isn't that an O(n) solution? O(n) to fill the table, and O(n) to iterate the table? Seems to me then that there's something missing in the question.

Comment: @user3386109 hashing probably not allowed, it is indeed O(n). Maybe O(k) extra space restriction missing

Comment: @KrassiEm Yea Using a Map (hash table) makes sense. To be fair this isn't the full context I'm trying to solve this in a homework question and can't use Maps but that should be a valid solution!

Comment: @juvian My o(nk) method relies on the fact that there can't be more than k-1 such elements and then I find the in/k th largest elements (i = 1 to k-1) Using the Select algorithm O(n) and check those if they match

Comment: @juvian Nice find! I think it's a duplicate I'll close this

Comment: I attempted to answer a [cross-post of this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/100883) on [cs.se]